# Detecting File System in installation of Ubuntu 20.04 takes really long

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-20.04

I am currently installing Ubuntu 20.04 on my computer and chose the 'Erase disk and clean install' function, without internet, a minimal installation and no automatic driver installation.

Right now it's really slow with installing, constantly giving errors like:
`Warning: Source ID 20763 was not found when attempting to remove it Glib.sources_remove(self.rows_changed)`

The ID is slowly rising, like with +400 every 2 minutes. But I doubt this should be happening, or that the ubuntu installation should be taking this long.

Does anybody know a work around, or how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so...

After rebooting 4 times, doing different things like choosing 'something else' and creating the partitions myself, and turning of 'Fast Boot' in the BIOS.

I have now chosen te same settings again, except for installing the normal version, instead of the minimum version.

All seems to work well now!